# Getting an application/object variable error, while trying to select the range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to set the Range with the following lines of code, after a loop, but it gives me an Application/Object variable error, can someone please help, erroring out at the SET R line

Variables, R as Range, irows and derows as integers, having given the col as static text, but there are six columns, i need the range to be set from A13 to A18

```
    derows = ((actcell.Row) + 2) --13
    irows = ((actcell.Row) + 2)  --13
    
    Rows(irows).Activate
     
    Do
   
    irows = irows + 1
    If Rows(irows).Find("*") Is Nothing Then Exit Do
    Loop
   
  Set R = csvWsDes.Range(Cells(derows, 1), Cells(irows, 6)).Select
```

Comment: Is the `--13` a comment showing us what the value is?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're trying to `Set` a `Range` and `Select` it at the same time.  Split the line `Set R = csvWsDes.Range(Cells(derows, 1), Cells(irows, 6)).Select` into two lines.  First `Set` it, then `Select` it.

```
Set R = csvWsDes.Range(Cells(derows, 1), Cells(irows, 6))
R.Select
```

Also, it's quite likely that you don't need to use the `.Select` method for whatever you're doing, but that's outside the scope of this question.